# Bash Regex Capture Groups

Tags: regex, bash, grep, pcre

I have a single string that is this kind of format:

```
"Mike H<michael.haken@email1.com>" michael.haken@email2.com "Mike H<hakenmt@email1.com>"
```

If I was writing a normal regex in JS, C#, etc, I'd do this

```
(?:"(.+?)"|'(.+?)'|(\S+))
```

And iterate the match groups to grab each string, ideally without the quotes. I ultimately want to add each value to an array, so in the example, I'd end up with 3 items in an array as follows:

```
Mike H<michael.haken@email1.com>
michael.haken@email2.com 
Mike H<hakenmt@email1.com>
```

I can't figure out how to replicate this functionality with `grep` or `sed` or bash regex's. I've tried some things like

```
echo "$email" | grep -oP "\"\K(.+?)(?=\")|'\K(.+?)(?=')|(\S+)"
```

The problem with this is that while it kind of mimics the functionality of capture groups, it doesn't really work with multiples, so I get captures like

```
"Mike
H<michael.haken@email1.com>"
 michael.haken@email2.com
```

If I remove the look ahead/behind logic, I at least get the 3 strings, but the first and last are still wrapped in quotes. In that approach, I pipe the output to `read` so I can individually add each string to the array, but I'm open to other options.

EDIT:

I think my input example may have been confusing, it's just a possible input. The real input could be double quoted, single quoted, or non-quoted (without spaces) strings in any order with any quantity. The Javascript/C# regex I provided is the real behavior I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Please post the desired output.

Comment: Question has been updated with the desired output.

Comment: As a convention, don't use capitals for Bash variables and DO quote them in quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was able to do that worked, but wasn't as concise as I wanted the code to be:

```
arr=()
while read line; do
  line="${line//\"/}"
  arr+=("${line//\'/}")
done < <(echo $email | grep -oP "\"(.+?)\"|'(.+?)'|(\S+)")
```

This gave me an array of the capturing group and handled the input in any order, wrapped in double or single quotes or none at all if it didn't have a space. It also provided the elements in the array without the wrapping quotes. Appreciate all of the suggestions.

Answer (score 6):

You can use Perl:

```
$ email='"Mike H<michael.haken@email1.com>" michael.haken@email2.com "Mike H<hakenmt@email1.com>"'
$ echo "$email" | perl -lane 'while (/"([^"]+)"|(\S+)/g) {print $1 ? $1 : $2}' 
Mike H<michael.haken@email1.com>
michael.haken@email2.com
Mike H<hakenmt@email1.com>
```

Or in pure Bash, it gets kinda wordy:

```
re='\"([^\"]+)\"[[:space:]]*|([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]*'
while [[ $email =~ $re ]]; do
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    i=${#BASH_REMATCH}
    email=${email:i}
done 
# same output
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `sed` to achieve that,

```
$ sed -r 's/"(.*)" (.*)"(.*)"/\1\n\2\n\3/g' <<< "$EMAIL"
Mike H<michael.haken@email1.com>
michael.haken@email2.com 
Mike H<hakenmt@email1.com>
```

Comment: This works if I know the input format; what I provided was just representative of a possible input, essentially it's an input string that was space delimited strings that may or may not be wrapped in double or single quotes to handle spaces inside the quoted string. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

Your first expression is fine; just be careful with the quotes (use single quotes when `\` are present). In the end trim the `"` with sed.

```
$ echo $mail | grep -Po '".*?"|\S+' | sed -r 's/"$|^"//g'
Mike H<michael.haken@email1.com>
michael.haken@email2.com
Mike H<hakenmt@email1.com>
```

Comment: The problem with this answer is that is captures the double and single quotes from the input string as part of the output, but noted on the quote usage.

Comment: @hakenmt, thank you for the comment: my bad. I added an extra step to fit the requirements, but the solution is not very elegant...

Answer (score 1):

**gawk** + **bash** solution (adding each item to array):

```
email_str='"Mike H<michael.haken@email1.com>" michael.haken@email2.com "Mike H<hakenmt@email1.com>"'

readarray -t email_arr < <(awk -v FPAT="[^\"'[:space:]]+[^\"']+[^\"'[:space:]]+" \
                         '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i }' <<<$email_str)
```

---

Now, all items are in `email_arr`

Accessing the 2nd item:

```
echo "${email_arr[1]}"
michael.haken@email2.com
```

Accessing the 3rd item:

```
echo "${email_arr[3]}"
Mike H<hakenmt@email1.com>
```

Comment: This did work for me to achieve the regex behavior and array result I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using `gawk` where you can set multi-line `RS`.

```
awk -v RS='"|" ' 'NF' inputfile
Mike H<michael.haken@email1.com>
michael.haken@email2.com
Mike H<hakenmt@email1.com>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your regex like this :

```
grep -oP '("?\s*)\K.*?(?=")' file
```

Output:

```
Mike H<michael.haken@email1.com>
michael.haken@email2.com
Mike H<hakenmt@email1.com>
```

Comment: That pattern assumes the input is always in that order; the input was supposed to be representative of a possible input pattern, which is an input string containing space delimited strings that may or may not be wrapped in single or double quotes to handle white space inside the string.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk and `FPAT` to *[define fields by content](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html)*:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FPAT="([^ ]*)|(\"[^\"]*\")" }  # define a field to be space-separated or in quotes
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {               # iterate every field
        gsub(/^\"|\"$/,"",$i)          # remove leading and trailing quotes
        print $i                       # output
    }
}' file
Mike H<michael.haken@email1.com>
michael.haken@email2.com
Mike H<hakenmt@email1.com>
```

Comment: This version didn't account for the single quoted strings and if I have a trailing space after the last quoted string (for some reason), it adds a blank entry. This also doesn't add them to an array, but could be easily updated to do so. I think @RomanPerekhrest's version of this is closer.